# Como incluir una plantilla html para enviar por mail PHP?

Tags: php, template

Necesito pasar la variable con una plantilla para enviar y organizar el código.

```
define(FULLNAME, $fullname);
define(EMAIL, $email);

$body = include('../templete/welcome.php?name='.FULLNAME);

$header = "From: Team app <no-responder@company.com> \r\n";
$header .= "Bcc: company@gmail.com \r\n";
$header .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . " \r\n";
$header .= "Mime-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/html";

return $body;
mail(EMAIL, "¡Welcome to Dolphy!", $body, $header);
```

Comment: No me termina de quedar claro qué es lo que quieres hacer. En el código que compartes no hay plantilla de ningún tipo, ni se intenta agregar nada externo, ¿es eso lo que intentas hacer?¿leer un archivo HTML con la plantilla y enviarlo como cuerpo del mensaje?

Answer (score 1):

Creo que estas haciendo mal la llamada a la plantilla. Prueba asi:

```
define(FULLNAME, $fullname);
define(EMAIL, $email);

$body = file_get_contents('../templete/welcome.php');

$body = str_replace("nombrexxx", FULLNAME, $body);

$header = "From: Team app <no-responder@company.com> \r\n";
$header .= "Bcc: company@gmail.com \r\n";
$header .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . " \r\n";
$header .= "Mime-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/html";

return $body;
mail(EMAIL, "¡Welcome to Dolphy!", $body, $header);
```

Solo tendrías que cambiar tu fichero `welcome.php`, para que donde tengas la variable que pasas, se ponga `nombrexxx`. De esta forma con la instrucción `str_replace` cambiaras por el valor que pasas

Comment: lo logré de esta manera

Answer (score 0):

lo logre de esta manera

```
function send_ResetPass($fullname, $email, $pass){
$newpassmd5 = md5($pass);

$path = '../templete/pass.html';
if(file_exists($path)){
    $tpl = file_get_contents($path);
}
$body = str_replace('{{content}}', strtoupper($fullname), $tpl);
$body = str_replace('{{pass}}', $pass, $body);

$header = "From: El equipo Dolphy <no-responder@correo.com> \r\n";
$header .= "Bcc: correo@gmail.com \r\n";
$header .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . " \r\n";
$header .= "Mime-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/html";

if (mail($email, "Alguien solicitó una nueva contraseña para tu cuenta de Dolphy", $body, $header)) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE pw_user SET password ='$newpassmd5' WHERE user = '$email'");
}
```

}